I can't understand the meaning of the name of the ship ''Coastal Eagle point''
I came across the following text in my textbook:

Four tugboats work together to free the oil tanker ''Coastal Eagle
Point'' that ran aground while attempting to navigate a channel
in Tampa Bay.

I can't understand the meaning of the name of the tanker. I guess that Coastal Eagle is some kind of bird, but what is the word point here?
EDIT: I found this on the internet:
The Eagle Point Refinery in West Deptford Township was a 1,000-acre (400 ha) oil refinery that had once been a tomato-processing factory and became a U.S. Army munitions depot during World Wars I and II. The property was acquired by Texaco and began refining operations in 1949.[41] It was purchased by Coastal Oil in May 1985[42] and in 1997 became foreign trade Special Purpose Subzone 142C.[28] In January 2004, it was bought by Sunoco, which announced its permanent closure in 2010.[42] The plant is being disassembled by 2015 so that a new facility can be planned by Sunoco.[43] Its adjacent tank farm, with tanker truck, rail, pipeline, and marine transfer operations, remain active.[44][45]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_of_Paulsboro#Facilities
I think now we can understand where the name of the ship comes from

Why do you assume the name of a boat should have a specific "meaning" accessible to even native Anglophones, let alone non-native speakers? Note that Point often denotes a place (often, an elevated coastal landmark feature). There are lots of written references to Eagle Point as a place name, and I can't see any reason why a boat based at such a place wouldn't be prefixed by the word coastal to distinguish it from another boat based there that often sailed further into the high seas.

...in short, I would "parse" the name as coastal + (eagle point) if I wanted to parse it at all. But I wouldn't normally attempt to parse a boat name anyway.

First HIT on google: https://www.epa.gov/enforcement/coastal-eagle-point-refining-settlement Names are not usually parsed. There could be an eagle point in some mountain or other but these jokers wanted to make sure people get it was on the coast.

It's actually on the Delaware River, the river that separates Pennsylvania and New Jersey.

It's common for a company to name all its ships starting with the same word: sometimes this is the company name or another business name, but not always. Maybe there are other Coastal ships. There's an Aviation SE but I don't think there's a maritime one, so you'll have to ask elsewhere if you want to know why.

Names, especially of ships, named houses, race horses, etc. don't always make sense. As far as I know there is no species called "Coastal Eagle." "Point" has a meaning related to coastal topography:

6a: a projecting usually tapering piece of land or a sharp prominence

This seems like the most relevant meaning of "point", but there's no need to assemble all three words into a meaningful phrase. By the way, this EPA settlement shows that it's the name of the oil company that owns the tanker, though this picture of the ship in dry dock suggests that it is also the effective name of the ship.

Here's a relevant usage chart. Howsoever capitalized, all variants of coastal eagle,Coastal eagle,Coastal Eagle are as nothing compared to Eagle Point. Which latter is obviously a well-known and/or common "place name" (or perhaps "place name adopted as company name").

@FumbleFingers I considered elaborating—eagles like to nest in lofty places like a "sharp prominence"—but left it out; "eagle point" is a common collocation in place names (the name of my neighborhood, in fact!) but still not a phrase of its own.

I think the answer's fine as it stands - it's just that the OP "misparsed" the first two words as a "unit", when it should have been the last two words. And guessing that the last two words probably identify a place, I searched case-sensitive NGrams for just the capitalized version of that, to compare against all permutations for the first two words. Which pretty much proved that I was on the same correct track as you.

Coastal Refining and Marketing (oil company) owned 962 gas stations in 33 US states and was supplied by four refineries, including one in Eagle Point, New Jersey,
